# Add overlay to image.file

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a black overlay with 50% opacity to  to my `Image.file`. Based on what I am seeing online, color filtered is not what I require as that it changes the tint entirely.

```
: GridView.count(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                          childAspectRatio: (80 / 150),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          children:
                              List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                            return ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index],
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tint depends on which `BlendMode` you chose when using `ColorFiltered`. This is the one way to get the desired filter on top of an image using `colorFilter` property of a `Container`:

```dart
...
return Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
    image: new DecorationImage(
      image: FileImage(widget.imageArray[index]),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Another option is to use a `Stack`, put the `ClipRRect` to the outside for the desire UI:

```dart
return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Image.file(widget.imageArray[index], fit: BoxFit.fill),
        Opacity(
            opacity: 0.5,
            child: Container(
                width: 128, height: 128, color: Colors.black)),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `Opacity` and `Stack` widgets to get that effect:

```dart
 Stack(
      children: [
        FlutterLogo(size: 128),
        Opacity(opacity: 0.5, child: Container(width: 128, height: 128, color: Colors.black)),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView.count(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                          childAspectRatio: (80 / 150),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          children:
                              List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                            return ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Stack(children:[
Image.file(widget.imageArray[index],
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
Container(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
]),
),
```